# Text input with IF statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am creating a very simple story based "game" where there is a question with choices (not radio buttons etc) and the user has to type in the choices that's been given to them. I am not very good with JavaScript as you will see...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamescript.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (door == "Door 1", "door 1"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else if (door == "Door 2", "door 2"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any errors but when I type in something random/or leave blank, it's meant to say "Choose a door" but it's displaying anything i type into the text box. This code might be wrong, i'm guessing it most likely is..I didn't want to come online for help but have no one else to ask. All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/djrkgby9/

Comment: Did you debug your application?

Comment: `door == "Door 1", "door 1"` <-- learn what the comma operator does. It does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than execute the same line of code in separate conditions, why not utilize a simple switch?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        switch(door.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'door 1':
            case 'door 2':
                document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax on your `if` statements is wrong. Change your `if` statements to use proper "or" syntax:

```js
function myFunction(){
    var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (door == "Door 1" || door == "door 1"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else if (door == "Door 2" || door == "door 2"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>


</body>
```

Comment: why even use the or, just lower case the string and compare.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and help!! If the user was to enter Door 1, do i repeat the process for another question?

Comment: Not sure if I can answer that. That just depends on how you want your game to flow. The key here is that there was a syntax error. There probably was an error showing up, but it was just being suppressed. I would suggest using the F12 debug tools to investigate things like this.

Comment: I was using the F12 in Chrome but no errors showed up..why i came here to ask lol, as I knew something wasn't right but had no one to ask. Anyway, thanks a lot for help and everyone else who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You could make use ot [toLowerCase()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) and then compare `door` to "door 1", etc.

```
function myFunction(){
var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();

if (door == "door 1"){
    document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
}else if (door == "door 2"){
    document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered" + door;
}else{
    document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
}
```

In case you need, you can use `||` (or) [logical operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) and evaluate `if (door == "Door 1" || door =="door 1")`

Answer (score 0):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) `,` evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand. Your issue is that the first `if` check is always returning true.

```
function myFunction(){
    var doorVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var door = document.getElementById("door");
    // this could just as well be an object
    var acceptedResponses = ["Door1", "door1", "Door2", "door2"];
    if (acceptedResponses.indexOf(doorVal) !== -1) {
      door.innerHTML = "You have entered " + door;
    } else {
      door.innerHTML = "You must enter a door!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might even just want to use a regex if they are going to be so similar.